# Reclaim owndership of anonymous question

Tags: support

*Before* joining the Video Production Community, I posted a question.  *I have since joined*.

Since the posting was done using my email address, how can I have that question "**reclaimed**" by, or **re-assigned** to, my official personal Stack Exchange account?

Or is that not possible?

Question was [***this***](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/36073/why-does-ffprobe-report-color-space-as-unknown).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible, and I think the best way to currently do this is to request via the [Contact Us](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link, which goes direct to SE staff.

If you used the same email address it should be a no-brainer for the accounts to be merged.